# Does PageFactory.InitElements support Windows XP

Tags: webdriver, windows-xp, pageobjects

Does anyone know if Selenium PageFactory.InitElements supports Windows XP?

In my case, instead of Lazy initialization of WebElement it tries to find element on a page.
As far as I know it should create some kind of a proxy for WebElement and search for WebElement on a page at first call to this WebElement.

The same code works on Windows 7 but not Windows XP. It throws NoSuchElement exception.

Comment: A NoSuchElementException suggests that the element is not on the page.  I suspect you have a slow loading element that will require an explicit wait.

Answer (score 0):

I'd surprised if PageFactory doesn't work on XP. I know no reason why it shouldn't. Although, be aware of browser version that is installed on XP. If it is not the same browser/version that you use on Win7, this may be because same element locator doesn't work properly in older browser.

What concerns me more, is that you use PageFactory at all. I [compared Page Object with PageFactory](http://automatictester.co.uk/2014/08/08/selenium-pagefactory-design-pattern/), and I struggle to find reasons why people should be bothered by this "cool" thingy.

Comment: Your blog post is not 100% accurate, I've added a comment showing you some ways to do the things that you say the PageFactory classes cannot do.  I use the PageFactory classes all the time and they work very well